# Colorbox Prototype error: invalid array length

Tags: jquery, prototype, colorbox

I have a following code to display images in colorbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$('a.gallery').colorbox({rel:'gal'});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

CMS I am working on is a mess. 
It has prototype, jquery, jquery-ui and many more.

In Firebug console I get following:
invalid array length
[Break On This Error]
this[i] = this[i + 1];

prototype.js line 387 (version 1.4.0)
which is:

```
shift: function() {
var result = this[0];
for (var i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++)
this[i] = this[i + 1];
this.length--;
return result;
},
```

All I get is a faded background and colorbox corners load (corners don't remove).

jQuery.noConflict(); didn't work either.

Please help!

Comment: I know this was over two years ago, but I've just run into this on a page that has jQuery 1.7.2 and prototype 1.4.  The call stack makes it look like jQuery's `dequeue` function is passing control over to prototype's `shift` function.  I'm not sure why yet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out.  It's happening because prototype.js extends (among many others) the native `Array.prototype.shift` function, and that extension contains the bug that's causing the error.  jQuery uses `shift` on [line 2109])(https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/jquery.js#L2109), among other places.  That's where it was breaking for me.

I don't expect this will help user1722113, but hopefully it helps someone down the line.

I can only think of two solutions:

1. ditch prototype.js (the better solution.  in general, overriding native functions is bad)
2. re-initialize Array.prototype.shift somehow, or replace it with an implementation that isn't broken